# Is there a way to instruct visual studio to auto add fields at the bottom of the class instead of the top?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, styles

```cs
namespace Guilds
{
  public class Wizard
  {
    public void Wear(IClothing clothing)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Puts on the {Robe} and {WizardHat}".Fmt(clothing));
    }

    IClothing _clothes;
    IWeapon   _weapon; // <== I want my fields added at the bottom of the class!
  }
}
```

I am aware that if you put your fields at the bottom, it will start adding subsequent ones to the bottom of the class as well. I would love to have this as the default behavior even for the first field.

This behavior is usually triggered when pressing Ctrl + . on top of an undeclared field.

Comment: what's stopping from declaring at bottom?

Comment: Nothing! I just want to be able to make it the default behavior, instead of forcing me to update it every time I forget to add a field to the bottom of the class.

Comment: I kinda think this would drive me nuts if I saw this in someone else's code..

Comment: @MikeChristensen I can understand that. But that's a preference. My rationale is that usually fields (in particular the private ones) are less important than other public members. Thereby I usually place them at the bottom.

Comment: @ciriarte - Fair enough.  I think the answer is *No*, there's no way to do that.  Maybe a third party formatter like reSharper can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Regionerate](http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/) and create your own format template. it's free tool to use with visual studio.

Edit: You can also use [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) because it seems that Regionerate and VS2012 do not work together (I have not tested that combination at all though. I have VS2010)

**Edit** Adding more to my previous reply. CodeMaid is really cool and you can specify the layout in configuration. Also in configuration, you can specify that file should be formatted on save. This way write your code in anyway you want and have it formatted when you press Ctrl+S! I am one happy user of CodeMaid. Also I am using Visual Studio 2013.